# Почему в PhoneGap-приложении не срабатывает событие backbutton?

Tags: android, phonegap, cordova

Вот код:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButton, false);

}, true);

function backButton(e) {

    myApp.alert('Back button');
    e.preventDefault();

}
```

Он должен выводить всплывающее окно из фреймфорка с надписью "Back button", однако всё что происходит при нажатии на кнопку "назад" - выход из приложения. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще странно и непонятно почему, но заработало так:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
  myApp.alert('Back button');
}
```